# What was done by this code? 1

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I tried to modify the Wiimote Whiteboard app for my final project. but my experience in the programming language C # is very little. in fact I learn C # just a few months.

I do not know what is the meaning of a few lines of code. can anyone help me?

```
    //??
    public event EventHandler Connected;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> Error;
    public event EventHandler ConnectionFailed;

    //?
    public Thread Worker;

    //??
    Object lockobj = new Object();

    //??
    public void ConnectWiiMotes(bool DisconnectOld)
    {
        lock(lockobj)
        {
            if (Worker != null && Worker.IsAlive)
                return;

            Worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                delegate() { this.Connect(DisconnectOld); }));
            Cancel = false;
            Worker.Start();
        }
    }

    //??
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }

    //??
    private void LogError(string error)
    {
        if (Error != null)
            Error(this, new EventArgs<string>(error));
    } here
```

Comment: Which lines dont you understand? The whole code or any specific line?

Comment: @Rohan: You can say that I do not understand the purpose of the overall code above.

Comment: Don't tell me you added the `1` to your title to make it unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
    // Assign event handlers, read more about events here: 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx
    public event EventHandler Connected;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> Error;
    public event EventHandler ConnectionFailed;

    // Creates a variable that defines a thread. (A unit under a process where some code run)
    // Read more about threads here: 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx
    public Thread Worker;

    Object lockobj = new Object();

    // Creates new thread (long story short: think about a thread as a process) that runs a method that somehow connects the wii motes.
    public void ConnectWiiMotes(bool DisconnectOld)
    {
        // Using the lockobj to ensure the method run once at a time
        // Read about the lock design pattern and C# locking here:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx
        lock (lockobj)
        {
            // Make sure the thread is not already running.
            if (Worker != null && Worker.IsAlive)
                return;

            // Runs the connection method inside the thread
            Worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                delegate() { this.Connect(DisconnectOld); }));
            Cancel = false;
            Worker.Start();
        }
    }

    // If you want to cancel the current connection, you set this property to true.
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }

    // In case of error, this method raises the error event with the error message. 
    // You can hook up to this event and catch the error later.
    private void LogError(string error)
    {
        if (Error != null)
            Error(this, new EventArgs<string>(error));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I do not understand the functionality behind this piece of code but technically i can assist you:**

```
 public event EventHandler Connected;
 public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> Error;
 public event EventHandler ConnectionFailed;
```

As you can see above 3 statements are the `declaration for three Event Handlers`.

Event Handlers are the one's which respond to a particular event and performs the corresponding `Callback` action

Here, you can consider successfully connected as one event , if any error occur as one event and connection failed as one event.

So, in each case there should be some callback happening. This event handler does that job.

Event Handler does that call back by anonymously calling a function using **delegate**

```
 public Thread Worker;

    //??
    Object lockobj = new Object();

    //??
    public void ConnectWiiMotes(bool DisconnectOld)
    {
        lock(lockobj)
        {
            if (Worker != null && Worker.IsAlive)
                return;

            Worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                delegate() { this.Connect(DisconnectOld); }));
            Cancel = false;
            Worker.Start();
        }
    }
```

You can see in the above piece of code, how the **delegate** is called to perform **call 
back**

`Lock()`  will make sure that no other worker thread gets access the protected code at the same time.

Event Handling and Delegates are little Advanced Concepts in C# , Once you understand ..you will start enjoying the power of them.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a basic framework for starting a thread and maintaining a few state variables and event handlers. There isn't much "implementation" in this code to explain. These are just simple language constructs.